# In Access VBA, how to verify if parent record has children before deleting it?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have Access database with many tables and forms for each of these tables.  I’ve setup table relationships (one-to-many) and enforce Referential Integrity for parent-child records.  My Forms have a Delete button to delete individual records, which does DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdDeleteRecord command.  Now, when I try to delete a record that has children I get an error 3200.  In the Form_Delete event I am currently verifying using a massage box to make sure the user wants to delete the record, if No, I Cancel the deletion.  I would like to know if there is a way to check if the current record user is trying to delete has children and therefore will not be able to be deleted and will give me the error.  Obviously access checks for related child records when the parent is deleted and throws this error and the record is not deleted.  I want to be able to check a property of the record or something like that to see if has children and cannot be deleted prior to actually deleting it and getting an error, in which case I want cancel that deletion.
Just to note, I know I can handle the error when it happens, but I want to do this check in the Delete event prior to actual deletion and getting the error.

Thanks for your help, Arthur.

Comment: Use DCount() function

Comment: Patrick, I don't believe DCount() will work in my application because I would need to know all table relationships ahead of time and names of those tables to use it in each DCount() and when new table relationships are created, I would have to edit my code to account for those.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to iterate the Relations collection and read the info about table/foreign table
Check this question from EE and the answer : https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/27266600/Access-VBA-getting-table-relationships.html

Comment: Thanks John, this looks promising, I am going to explore this and see how it will work for me.

Comment: @John interesting answer. On SO it is asked, if you post such a link, to copy or repharase at least the essential part of the content, so that if the link goes dead, the information stays.

Comment: @Patrick is not my solution...i have pointed the iteration of Relations collection but i cannot take credit for the solution provided...if the link goes bad then the future user that will try to use it will have a starting point to go...After All EE is solid from the 90s so it would be hard to say that the link will go bad "easily". Is pretty much the same when a question here in SO gets deleted/on hold/marked as duplicate due to similar question/answer ....as "easily" EE goes BAD this also applies for SO.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
I wrote this function.....

TableName is the table in referenced table
MasterFieldName the keyfield of this table.
KeyFieldValue the value you want to check.

Sorry for my comments in Italian.

```
Function F_AsChild(TableName As String, MasterFieldName As String, KeyFieldValue As String)

    Dim nx As Integer
    Dim ny As Integer


    Dim Rst As Recordset
    Dim Errore As Boolean
    Dim Trovato As Boolean
    Dim XX As Long
    ' La routine funziona esclusivamente a patto che la relazione sia di "one-to-many"

    XX = 0
    Trovato = False
    Errore = False
    ' Conto il mumero di relazioni che ho a disposizione.


    ' Ciclo sulle Releazioni
    For nx = 0 To CurrentDb.Relations.Count - 1

        ' Nel caso ho trovato il dato esco
        If Trovato Then Exit For


        ' Se mi trovo sulla tabella
        If CurrentDb.Relations(nx).Table = TableName Then



            For ny = 0 To CurrentDb.Relations(nx).Fields.Count - 1

                If MasterFieldName <> CurrentDb.Relations(nx).Fields(ny).Name Then
                    Errore = True
                    Trovato = True
                Else

                    XX = XX + DCount(CurrentDb.Relations(nx).Fields(ny).ForeignName, CurrentDb.Relations(nx).ForeignTable, CurrentDb.Relations(nx).Fields(ny).ForeignName + "='" + Trim(KeyFieldValue) + "'")

                End If

                If Trovato Then Exit For

            Next ny
        End If



    Next

    If Errore Then
        F_AsChild = -1
    Else
        F_AsChild = XX
    End If


End Function
```